# How to assign two IP addresses (one DHCP, one static) to a NIC using WMI?

Tags: windows, networking, dhcp, nic, wmi

Found question and great answer: [WMI and adding Multiple IP Addresses?](https://serverfault.com/questions/181039/wmi-and-adding-multiple-ip-addresses) However this only explains how to add multiple static IP addresses. I am looking how to configure a dynamic (DHCP) and at least one static IP address on the same NIC. But only manage to get one or the other to work. I am looking for a WMI solution for WinXP, Vista and Win7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't do this to a network adapter on Windows using any method, not just WMI.

Comment: Yeah, I don't think this is possible. I just double checked for sanity and you can't add multiple IP's to a NIC with DHCP through the GUI.

Comment: IIRC you can add *alternative* addresses to adapters with DHCP set and you can add multiple fixed IPs. But that's as far as it goes.

Comment: Thanks. I will do some research about maybe doing it with a virtual NIC. If I don't figure it out I'll ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is](http://www.petri.co.il/configure_tcp_ip_to_use_dhcp_and_a_static_ip_address_at_the_same_time.htm) an interesting article that does what you need but employing two steps - DHCP and registry editing.

It's not a solution per se, but can be implemented as one if you really have the need.

Answer (score 0):

This has just turned reality (for the latest version of Windows only, probably).

Quoting myself:

> There is a new property called `dhcpstaticipcoexistence` in the `netsh interface ipv4` `set interface` command, which can be set to `enabled` and this interface can be configured with multiple static IPs along with a DHCP-configured IP. However this has to be done with the `netsh` `add address` command, not yet possible via the GUI.

https://superuser.com/a/1250941/771867